# Problem installing Ubuntu on MacBook

Tags: boot, mac

I have a macbook that cannot get past the startup splash and the spinning wheel under the Apple logo.

*edit bodhi.zazen* - removed extra information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Please edit it to include what model of Mac it is, and what you have done so far, e.g. what did you download, how did you try to install, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately because it won't boot, I haven't the access to that info.

Comment: Purchase hardware with Ubuntu pre-installed ?

Comment: Might very well be hardware malfunction. Press D when you start the computer to reach Apple Hardware Test. Then initiate the basic memory test to see if the hard-drive is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Burn Ubuntu to a USB drive, using whatever your favorite program is. Plug it into the Mac and hold the `Option/ALT` key to enter the built-in boot menu of the Mac. Select the USB drive and boot from it.

Comment: It isn't recognizing the drive, maybe I have the wrong iso...it came from a windows download. If I download it from my Ubuntu will that make a difference? Is there a bios mode to boot into??? I know nothing about apple.

Comment: Macs have a built-in bootloader that can be accessed by holding down the option or alt key as soon as you turn it on. Definitely re-download the ISO from the Ubuntu website and re-burn it.